# Standard deviation problem for short cut technique

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

## Revised-GRE QUESTION

I know how to evaluate the standard deviation and mean and also I have basic knowledge about the bell curve. But whenever I have to solve some problems  related standard deviation within very short amount of time,  its very hard to calculate in details.

For example:I have to  find out that standard deviation from which chart is bigger , or are they equal?

**Therefore I want to know  how to  have a good insight  to  get right these questions without doing lengthy equation?**

[image]

Comment: To compare these, subtract $30$ from every observation (this does not change the variance).  The data on the left is just the same as on the right with the opposite sign, so the variance is the same.

Comment: Can you check the edited question please?

Comment: Same mean, $30$, but the one on the right is concentrated on the wings while the one on the left is concentrated at the mean, so the variance on the right is greater.

Comment: Can you  please write it a bit technically?

Comment: Not sure what you are after.  It's easy enough to write out exactly.  In each case, the mean is $30$, so subtract that from every data point.  On the right we have $10$ terms on the wings, so we get $10(20)^2$ from the wings alone, while on the left you only get $6(20)^2$.  The contributions from the terms that are now $\pm 10$ match, so they don't matter for your purposes.  Likewise, the middle term contributes $0$, so only the wings matter.  Not entirely sure what you are hoping for...for general data sets you can sometimes see very "fat tails" as here on the right, but not always.

Comment: Just conceptually:  Low variance means a big spike in the middle with very little out to the sides.  You increase the variance by pushing down the middle and getting more data out on the sides.  the further you can push stuff away from the mean, the higher the variance.  In this example, you've taken $4$ data points off the mean and placed them at the extreme edges...the best way by far to increase variance.